# Multi-Page Dash App Callbacks Not Registering

Tags: python, flask, plotly-dash

I am working on my first Dash app (I have experience in Django and very little in Flask, which I know Dash is built on), but I am having trouble with the routing and registering of callbacks for new pages.
I have read a few articles on the subject such as: https://dash.plot.ly/urls

Currently I have my main app.py:

```
from app1 import build as app1

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])
server = app.server
app.config.suppress_callback_exceptions = True


body = html.Div([
    dcc.Location(id='url', refresh=False),
    html.Div(id='page-content')
], id='body')

app.layout = html.Div([navbar, body])


@app.callback(dash.dependencies.Output('page-content', 'children'),
              [dash.dependencies.Input('url', 'pathname')])
def display_page(pathname):
    if pathname == '/' or pathname == '' or pathname == '/index':
        return build_index_page()
    elif pathname == '/1':
        return app1.layout
    else:
        return html.H3('URL Error!')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

And then I would like to build out sub apps / graphs that will be loaded into the “html.Div(id=‘page-content’)”

App1 is its own sub dir with init.py and build.py where build will generate the layout and callbacks to be loaded. build.py:

```
from app import app

#layout = build_body()
# initialize_callbacks(app)

layout = html.Div([
    html.H3('App 1'),
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='app-1-dropdown',
        options=[
            {'label': 'App 1 - {}'.format(i), 'value': i} for i in [
                'NYC', 'MTL', 'LA'
            ]
        ]
    ),
    html.Div(id='app-1-display-value')
])


@app.callback(
    Output('app-1-display-value', 'children'),
    [Input('app-1-dropdown', 'value')])
def display_value(value):
    return 'You have selected "{}"'.format(value)
```

Eventually I would like to then make 2 other files, one to contain layout and one to contain the callbacks. You can see my original implementation commented out, but I just moved the code into build.py when it did not work. (The functionality was taken directly from the Dash example linked above.)

When I go to my second page, the content loads fine but the callback does not, so selecting an item from the drop down does not populate the div as it is supposed to.It is also supposed to trigger on load to show the initial value, but it does not do that either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out, but I am unsure about the "why"

If I edit app.py to be:

```
app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])
server = app.server
app.config.suppress_callback_exceptions = True
```

and create index.py to be:

```
from app1 import build as app1
from app import app


body = html.Div([
    dcc.Location(id='url', refresh=False),
    html.Div(id='page-content')
], id='body')

app.layout = html.Div([navbar, body])


@app.callback(dash.dependencies.Output('page-content', 'children'),
              [dash.dependencies.Input('url', 'pathname')])
def display_page(pathname):
    if pathname == '/' or pathname == '' or pathname == '/index':
        return build_index_page()
    elif pathname == '/1':
        return app1.layout
    else:
        return html.H3('URL Error!')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Then the code for build.py works! As I said, I am unsure why this is the case...

Answer (score 1):

It might be a bit late, for people who come across similar questions, it could be helpful digging into the tutorial [here](https://dash.plotly.com/urls):

> Dash renders web applications as a "single-page app". This means that the application does not completely reload when the user navigates the application, making browsing very fast.

Also, you will find a component `app.validation_layout` which helps "completely" load all the callbacks of your sub-apps.

Basically, in some cases that a single app could trigger all callbacks when hosted separately but don't fire all callbacks when moved into a multi-page apps system.

So if you have a file structure:

```
- app.py
- index.py
- apps
   |-- __init__.py
   |-- app1.py
   |-- app2.py
```

All you need to do is to include wanted apps in `app.validation_layout`:

```
# "complete" layout
app.validation_layout = html.Div([
    import_module('apps.'+appname).layout 
    for appname in [apps-needed-to-be-loaded-completely]
])
```

If the above doesn't work, it might be helpful to check the [link](https://dash.plotly.com/callback-gotchas):

> However, in the case of more complex Dash apps that involve dynamic modification of the layout (such as multi-page apps), not every component appearing in your callbacks will be included in the initial layout. You can remove this restriction by disabling callback validation like this:

```
app.config.suppress_callback_exceptions = True
```